# PHP reading cvs file, when comma is left out

Tags: php, csv

Hello I am very new to PHP and I am trying to allow the user of the web page to upload a csv file and then store the rows into MySQL rows. Everything works great except for the cvs file is leaving out comma's at the end of every row causing the last cell and the first cell of the next row to merge. Where am I going wrong? Thanks!

PHP file, is executed upon form being submitted:

```
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);

$file_handle = fopen($target_file, "r");

while (!feof($file_handle) ) {

$line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);

//print $line_of_text[0] . $line_of_text[1]. $line_of_text[2] . "<BR>";



$arrlength = count($line_of_text);

for($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; $x = $x + 1){
echo $x. "   ".$line_of_text[$x]. "<br>";   
}


for($x = 7; $x < $arrlength; $x = $x + 6) {




 $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO `tooneate_MyTrivia`.`Question` (
   `CategoryId`,
   `Question`,
   `Group`, 
   `AnsOne`, 
   `AnsTwo`, 
   `AnsThree`, 
   `AnsFour`, 
   `CorrectAns`) VALUES (%d, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %d)",

                   GetSQLValueString($line_of_text[$x], "int"),//CatId
                   GetSQLValueString($line_of_text[$x+1], "text"),//Question
                   GetSQLValueString("1", "text"),//Group
                   GetSQLValueString($line_of_text[$x+2], "text"),//AnsOne
                   GetSQLValueString($line_of_text[$x+3], "text"),//AnsTwo
                   GetSQLValueString($line_of_text[$x+4], "text"),//AnsThree
                   GetSQLValueString($line_of_text[$x+5], "text"),//AnsFour
                   GetSQLValueString($line_of_text[$x+6], "int"));//CorrectAns

                   echo $insertSQL;
                    echo "<br>";
  mysql_select_db($database_TooNeate, $TooNeate);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $TooNeate) or die(mysql_error());

  $insertGoTo = "MyTrivia.php";
  if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
    $insertGoTo .= (strpos($insertGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
    $insertGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
  }
  header(sprintf("Location: %s", $insertGoTo));


}

}

fclose($file_handle);
```

Here is the sample csv file being uploaded:

Category Id,Question,Answer One,Answer Two,Answer Three,Answer Four,Correct Answer

1,Is the CSV file working?,Yes,No,Maybe,ehhh,1

1,Is this pretty dang cool?,Yes,No,Maybe,ehhh,4

In the csv file above the cell "Correct Answer" is merged with the next "1", and "1" with "1"

Thanks!

Comment: Your fgetcsv looks like it doesn't have enough parameters. $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024, ",");

Comment: Have you tried enabling `auto_detect_line_endings`, as the manual for `fgetcsv` suggests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

Basically I changed `fopen()` to `file()` so that each csv row would be its own array element in `$csv_rows`.  The `file()` function is sensitive to a `newline` to represent the line ending to handle where you are experiencing the missing `,`.

Then inside the loop, I split the row data into its own array with the PHP `str_getcsv()` function.

```
<?php
$target_dir = '';

$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]['tmp_name'],$target_file);

ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', true); // Optional if you need it

$csv_rows = file($target_file);

mysql_select_db($database_TooNeate, $TooNeate);

foreach( $csv_rows as $_key => $_row ):
    if($_key==0) continue; // Skip header row

    $_row_field_data = str_getcsv($_row);

    $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO `tooneate_MyTrivia`.`Question` (
        `CategoryId`,
        `Question`,
        `Group`, 
        `AnsOne`, 
        `AnsTwo`, 
        `AnsThree`, 
        `AnsFour`, 
        `CorrectAns`) VALUES (%d, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %d)",

        GetSQLValueString($_row_field_data[0], "int"),//CatId
        GetSQLValueString($_row_field_data[1], "text"),//Question
        GetSQLValueString("1", "text"),//Group
        GetSQLValueString($_row_field_data[2], "text"),//AnsOne
        GetSQLValueString($_row_field_data[3], "text"),//AnsTwo
        GetSQLValueString($_row_field_data[4], "text"),//AnsThree
        GetSQLValueString($_row_field_data[5], "text"),//AnsFour
        GetSQLValueString($_row_field_data[6], "int"));//CorrectAns

    echo $insertSQL;
    echo "<br/>";

    $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $TooNeate) or die(mysql_error());

endforeach;

$insertGoTo = "MyTrivia.php";
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])):
    $insertGoTo .= (strpos($insertGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
    $insertGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
endif;
//header(sprintf("Location: %s", $insertGoTo)); //  Uncomment this when you're ready for production.
?>
```

---

As mentioned by @CBroe in comments:

> Note: If PHP is not properly recognizing the line endings when reading
>   files either on or created by a Macintosh computer, enabling the
>   `auto_detect_line_endings` run-time configuration option may help
>   resolve the problem.

If you end up needing this, it can be set at the TOP of your PHP script with this command:

`ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', true);`

Comment: There are just a couple things I can think of. 1.) If you are using a Mac/Apple computer, re-save a fresh copy of your CSV but make sure you 'save-as' filetype '`Windows` Comma Separated Values'. CSV files come in many different flavors.  2.) What does a `var_dump($_row_field_data);` inside the loop give you? The `foreach` could only be executing once as said by @tNeate. Does the row data look normal?  Also, how many dumps did it do, is it the same as the number of rows you expect in your CSV?

Comment: Ahh, I might see it. We have `header()` inside of the loop. I'm suspicious if that sends you to a new page at the end of the first loop iteration, so it never gets to a second iteration.  Try moving the `header()` command after the `endforeach;`  I updated the answer to re-order some of the statements.

Comment: Yes, see updated answer.  I added a `$_key` assignment inside the `foreach()` declaration.  And then an `if()` statement to skip row `0`.  `foreach( $csv_rows as $_key => $_row ):
     if($_key==0) continue;`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73292/discussion-between-factoryaidan-and-t-neate).